# Taskbar context menu appearing behind taskbar when jump list is being shown

Tags: windows-8, taskbar, windows-8.1, context-menu

I've noticed something weird in Windows 8. When I right-click the taskbar, the context menu shows up normally. However, when right-clicking the taskbar with a Jump List open, the menu appears behind the taskbar, but I am still able to use it. The below screenshot is on Windows 8.1 Preview, but the same issue has been reported for all Windows 8, starting with Developer Preview. See [the question posted on Microsoft Answers](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1_pr-desktop/bug-report-the-infamous-windows-8-taskbar-bug/e3193a94-2df3-4f25-930f-eacd5f385762).

[image: Taskbar context menu appearing behind taskbar when jump list is being shown]

Is this a known Windows 8 bug? Upgrading to Windows 8.1 did not fix the problem...

Comment: I think you'd be a lot luckier asking this on the Microsoft support platform. Us random members are a lot less likely to know whether the bug is known than Microsoft moderators.

Comment: @Ariane Someone actually asked this on the Microsoft Answers site, but no one has responded. He said that he had found the issue on all editions of Windows 8 starting with Developer Preview.

Comment: Maybe insisting (bumping the thread) if it's been too long would do. I don't think they have a Stack Exchange-like system that automatically reminds them of unresolved issues, do they? Then I think it's perfectly fine to give them a reminder that no answer has been given yet, if the thread has been left unanswered for a long time. But now I see better. This concerns Windows 8 all short, including 8.1, eh? (I googled what a jump list was and tried, and went "ooooh".)